# Is it possible to store a query in a variable and use that variable in Insert query? "@countrid =SELECT id FROM COUNTRIES WHERE description = 'asdf';"

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I've been going through SQL migrations to insert data in a **SEQUENTIAL** manner specifically from parent to child.

I've **inserted data in the parent table**. Now I've to **store the primary key** value of that
specific row (*WHERE condition is defined in query for reference " where description = '1234'*") in a variable.

And while inserting data to the child table I've to use that primary key value stored in a variable in place of a foreign key column("**country_code_id**") of the child table.

I'm using Postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE Countries
(
    id        SERIAL,
    description VARCHAR(100),
    CONSTRAINT coutry_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE Cities
(
      country_code_id  int ,
      city_id     int,
      description   VARCHAR(100),
      CONSTRAINT cities_pkey PRIMARY KEY (city_id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_cities_countries FOREIGN KEY  (country_code_id) REFERENCES Countries (id)
);


INSERT INTO COUNTRIES (description) VALUES('asdf');
@countrid =  SELECT id FROM COUNTRIES WHERE description = 'asdf';
INSERT INTO cities VALUES (countrid, 1 , 'abc');
```

Comment: Database tags removed, please add back only relevant ones

Comment: I've to do this in Postgresql

Comment: Then why did you add a MySQL tag? Please dont spam tags, they are used to gather the correct audience for your question

Comment: Why you try to insert `abc` in a numeric field?

Comment: rectified @Jens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL does not have variables. The normal way to do this is to use `INSERT ... RETURNING`:

```
INSERT INTO countries (description) VALUES ('1234')
RETURNING id;
```

This will return the automatically generated primary key. You store that in a variable *on the client side* and run a second statement:

```
INSERT INTO cities (country_code_id, city_id, description)
VALUES (4711, 1, 'abc');
```

where 4711 is the value returned from the first statement. To avoid hard-coding the value, you can use a prepared statement, which also will boost performance.

An alternative, more complicated, solution is to run both statements in a single statement using a *common table expression*:

```
WITH country_ids AS (
   INSERT INTO countries (description) VALUES ('1234')
   RETURNING id
INSERT INTO (country_code_id, city_id, description)
SELECT id, 1, 'abc'
FROM country_ids;
```